# Check the full size of an email before sending Python smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I am having trouble sending a file by email through smtplib with Python.

I run the code on Kubernetes Cluster - Jupyter Notebook.

I get an error SMTPSenderRefused:

```
SMTPSenderRefused                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-9046ec8e66c3> in <module>
      1 # Send message
----> 2 s.send_message(msg)
      3 

/opt/app-root/conda/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py in send_message(self, msg, from_addr, to_addrs, mail_options, rcpt_options)
    965             flatmsg = bytesmsg.getvalue()
    966         return self.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, flatmsg, mail_options,
--> 967                              rcpt_options)
    968 
    969     def close(self):

/opt/app-root/conda/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py in sendmail(self, from_addr, to_addrs, msg, mail_options, rcpt_options)
    865             else:
    866                 self._rset()
--> 867             raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
    868         senderrs = {}
    869         if isinstance(to_addrs, str):

SMTPSenderRefused: (552, b'size limit exceeded',
```

It is a gzip file that weights about 15mb. I checked the max size that is possible to send:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mailhub.company.com') 
smtp.ehlo()   
max_limit_in_bytes = int( smtp.esmtp_features['size'] )
max_limit_in_bytes
```

And got 20971520, about 21mb.

So my questions are:

How can I get the exact size of the entire email (attachment + wrapper etc) before sending?

Is there a way to limit as much as possible the size of the email to allow more space for the file?

I tried sending the same file and email body directly through Outlook and got no issue. This only happens when I try through Python.

Here is my email sender function:

```
def emailer():
# instance of MIMEMultipart
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# Text message to be sent in the body of the mail
text = """\
Report delivery #12345

"""
# attach the message body with the msg instance
msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))

# File to be sent
data_out = !pwd
db_file = 'TEST_2020-10-20.csv.gz'
fileAbsolutePath = data_out[0]+'/'+db_file
attachment = open(fileAbsolutePath, "rb")

# instance of MIMEBase and named as p
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

# To change the payload into encoded form
p.set_payload((attachment).read())

# encode into base64
encoders.encode_base64(p)

p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

# Attach the file to be emailed
msg.attach(p)

msg['Subject'] = f'Report #12345'
msg['From'] = "email@company.com"
msg['To'] = "email@company.com"

# Connect to the SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('mailhub.company.com', 25)

# start TLS for security
s.starttls()

# Send message
s.send_message(msg)

# terminating the session
s.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try running this from your desktop? BTW I can't imagine this has anything to do with kubernetes so I removed the tag.

Comment: I have to run it from Kubernetes to have email sending privileges to my company mailhub. It won't let me access the server from local machine. I mentioned Kubernetes as the issue seems to be on sending. Isn't Kubernetes the place where such config would be managed?

Comment: No. Kubernetes doesn't work at that level.

Comment: Can you check whether `send_message()` succeeds if you do not attach `p` to `msg`, or if you do not call `p.set_payload()`? Also please try the code that I posted in my answer, and extend your answer with *Update: ...*

Answer (score 0):

From the [python docs for smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused):

```
exception smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused
    Sender address refused. In addition to the attributes set by on all SMTPResponseException exceptions, this sets ‘sender’ to the string that the SMTP server refused.
```

which, if the error message in your post is correct, indicates the sender address is too long. Based on the code you post, it does not appear to be, so put a try/except and print `sender` to see what smtplib thinks the sender is:

```
try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP('mailhub.company.com', 25)
    ...
except smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused as exc:
    print('error sending:', exc.sender)
    raise
```

Also, please be specific about where the error occurs, I could not tell if it is in the `SMTP()` function, the `starttls()` function, or the `send_message()` function.